# How can I authenticate mongodb server identity via mongodb shell?

Tags: mongodb

I am trying to deploy a mongodb instance in my environment. I have settled a ssl connection so it is possible to authenticate clients (using a certificate they enter and agreed root ca by both the server and the client). Is there a way to authenticate the server identity too? (I could not find any reference to this issue)

I would like to use the mongo shell (without any side programming)

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

> I am trying to deploy a mongodb instance in my environment. I have
>   settled a ssl connection so it is possible to authenticate clients
>   (using a certificate they enter and agreed root ca by both the server
>   and the client). Is there a way to authenticate the server identity
>   too? (I could not find any reference to this issue) . I would like to
>   use the mongo shell (without any side programming).

As per MongoDB documentation [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/authentication-mechanisms/#security-authentication-mechanisms) MongoDB supports the following authentication mechanisms:

- [SCRAM](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/security-scram/)
  (Default)
- [MongoDB
  Challenge and Response (MONGODB-CR)](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/security-mongodb-cr/) (Deprecated as of MongoDB
  3.6)
- [x.509
  Certificate Authentication](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/security-x.509/).

*`New in version 2.6.`*

MongoDB supports **`x.509`** certificate authentication for client authentication and internal authentication of the members of replica sets and sharded clusters.

**`x.509`** certificate authentication requires a secure [TLS/SSL connection](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/configure-ssl/).

### **Certificate Authority**

For production use, your MongoDB deployment should use valid certificates generated and signed by a single certificate authority. You or your organization can generate and maintain an independent certificate authority, or use certificates generated by a third-party TLS/SSL vendor.

### **Client x.509 Certificates**

To authenticate to servers, clients can use `x.509` certificates instead of usernames and passwords.

***Client Certificate Requirements***

The client certificate must have the following properties:

- A single Certificate Authority (CA) must issue the certificates for
  both the client and the server.
- Client certificates must contain the following fields:

  keyUsage = digitalSignature
  extendedKeyUsage = clientAuth
- Each unique MongoDB user must have a unique certificate.
- A client x.509 certificate’s subject, which contains the
  Distinguished Name (DN), must differ from that of a [Member
  x.509 Certificate](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/configure-x509-member-authentication/#x509-member-certificate). Specifically, the subjects must differ with
  regards to at least one of the following attributes: Organization
  (O), the Organizational Unit (OU) or the Domain Component (DC).

> **`WARNING`**
>   If a client x.509 certificate’s subject has the same O, OU, and DC
>   combination as the Member
>   x.509 Certificate, the client will be identified as a cluster
>   member and granted full permission on the system.

For your further ref [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/enable-authentication/)